# Literature request for books / review papers on gravitation, gauge theories and related mathematics

Tags: general-relativity, resource-recommendations, gauge-theory, mathematics

Similar to [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/193/best-books-for-mathematical-background/2592#2592) reference, are there more such references / works [including textbooks] available in the literature?
(A list would be greatly welcomed and appreciated.)

Comment: Exactly what sort of references are you looking for?

Comment: Both textbooks and review papers.

Comment: Yes, but about what, and with what characteristics? What information are you looking for, or what do you want to learn about? "Gravitation and gauge theories" is a _huge_ subject, and we already have that split up into a couple of book recommendation questions. What do you need that you can't get from those questions?

Comment: (Basically I'm searching for a (one-volume if possible) comprehensive survey of the mathematics underlying gauge theories and gravitation - (similar to the cited paper). - I'm wondering if there are more such works.)