# Books on representation theory

Tags: resource-recommendations, group-theory, group-representations, lie-algebra, representation-theory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best books for mathematical background?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/193/best-books-for-mathematical-background)

I'm looking for a textbook on the group/representation theory for a student-physicist. The main questions of interest are representations of SO, SU and the Lorentz/Poincare group in various dimensions (or maybe some other topics that i've missed but important for particle physics).

Comment: Possibly duplicate: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/193/2451

Comment: A book suitable for you would be "Lie Algebras in Particle Physics" by Howard Georgi. http://books.google.dk/books/about/Lie_Algebras_in_Particle_Physics.html?id=g4yEuH5rBMUC&redir_esc=y

Comment: Etingof, Vaintrob, et. al, [_Intro to rep theory_](http://math.mit.edu/~etingof/replect.pdf), 2011.