# Mathematical Physics Book Recommendation

Tags: mathematical-physics, soft-question, resource-recommendations, education, mathematics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best books for mathematical background?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/193/best-books-for-mathematical-background)

I want to learn contemporary mathematical physics, so that, for example, I can read Witten's latest paper without checking other sources again and again to find some basic definitions and theorems. I know it need a long time and intensive efforts, but are there any good books related so that I can follow them in one or two years? I have learned physics theories that come before the quantum field theory, including general relativity. And I know differential geometry, category, etc.

Comment: Mathematical physics is just too broad at this point. If you pick a particular area, people can point you to useful references. As a start, you can't go wrong reading Nakahara's, "Geometry, Topology and Physics, and Nash's "Differential Topology and Quantum Field Theory". And learn quantum field theory.

Comment: I don't think you can expect useful advice without narrowing things down, you'll just get everybody's favorite math book, which will send you on a wild goose chase. There are many math physics books because each one had different purpose, you'd have to decide what is yours.

Comment: This question seems rather vague and not well suited to this stack exchange.

Answer (score 4):

Start by reading Witten's early papers.  He wasn't able to expect his audience to know all the math already, so he often did a very nice job of explaining it.

For example,

- Supersymmetry Algebras That Include Topological Charges
- Search for a Realistic Kaluza-Klein Theory
- A Simple Proof of the Positive Energy Theorem
- Constraints on Supersymmetry Breaking
- Dynamical Breaking of Supersymmetry
- Global Aspects of Current Algebra
- Current Algebra, Baryons, and Quark Confinement
- Non-Abelian Bosonization in 2d
- Strings on Orbifolds
- Supersymmetry & Morse Theory
- Baryons in the 1/N expansion
- Verlinde Algebra & the Cohomology of the Grassmannian
- Gravitational Anomalies
- ...

Comment: Great! what papers would you recommend to start with?

Comment: @LarryHarson  I've listed a few of Witten's papers in the main body of the text.  I don't think I can sensibly recommend starting with any particular paper, certainly not without knowing what you're interested in studying.

Answer (score 3):

I have not read Witten's papers, but if you're willing to look at a senior undergrad, first year grad, text, I'd suggest [Hassani's](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387985794).  It is very broad in scope, and provides a good introduction to a number of areas of mathematical physics.

Answer (score 0):

This is quite late. I found [Mathematical Perspectives on Theoretical Physics: A Journey from Black Holes to Superstrings](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1860943640) quite suitable for what you ask.

Comment: The Table of Contents of this book does look very tempting. How did you perceive this book? The Amazon reviews seem to be very negative

Comment: I do not work in String theory. So I do not wish to say anything about the review in Amazon. I use the book as a reference and handbook for the mathematics.