# Which are the best introductory books for topology, algebraic geometry, differential geometry, manifolds, etc, needed for string theory?

Tags: string-theory, mathematical-physics, differential-geometry, resource-recommendations, topology

Which are the best introductory books for topology, algebraic geometry, differential geometry, manifolds, etc, needed for string theory?

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/193/2451 and links therein.

Comment: 1. Intro to Smooth Manifolds - Lee

2. Riemannian Geometry and Geometric Analysis - Jost

3. Complex Geometry: An Introduction - Huybrechts 

4. Algebraic Topology - Hatcher

5. Algebraic Geometry - Hartshorne

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nakahara's [book](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Geometry-Topology-Physics-Edition-Graduate/dp/0750306068/ref=sr_1_29?ie=UTF8&qid=1360865358&sr=8-29) is a classic.
I would also suggest Isham's [book](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Differential-Geometry-Physicists-Scientific-Lecture/dp/9810235623/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1360865345&sr=8-2) (really useful for Lie groups/algebras and GR).