# Which are the best mathematical methods books for which topic for a physics undergrad?

Tags: mathematical-physics, resource-recommendations, education

I am a physics undergraduate and I would be glad if you share your opinion about which books are best for which topics in mathematical methods, from very basic to advanced. (Like you some say Tom Apostol is good for calculus or Riley Hobson is good for vector calculus(just sayin'))

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mathematical physics text with plenty of applications](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/135043/)

Comment: Probably other similar queries, if you look in the sidebar to the above & this post

Comment: @KyleKanos You misinterpreted my question! What I am asking is which book is best for which topic, not a single book for everything or a book which also shows the application of the math. Thank you!

Comment: Then you want https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/12175/25301, but this ask of yours is excessively broad for this Q&A format.

Answer (score 1):

A textbook with a wide variety of explanations and exercises and that has provided me with all the new maths I was unfamiliar with as an undergraduate would be ‘Mathematical Techniques’ by Jordan and Smith. It does apply the mathematics to physicist perspective in an informative way, with very little jargon.

Comment: What I am asking is which book is best for which topic, not a single book for everything or a book which also shows the application of the math.