# Best resources to self learn, from scratch, mathematics as it appears in physics

Tags: resource-recommendations, education, mathematics

What are the best resources to learn, from scratch, mathematics as it appears in physics?

I would like to relearn *everything* besides basic enumeration / counting, and have absolutely zero understanding of physics. My apologies if the question is super ill formed: I would just like to learn some mathematics and am narrowing that down.

Comment: hey to you both, i saw the math section there, but am serious enough about this to ask for an answer, IMHO :)

Comment: oh i saw this http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/193/ for which the title is confusing. may be this answers my question, cheers!

Comment: @JohnRennie any ideas what i could add to get to https://www.amazon.com/dp/0471198269/?tag=stackoverfl08-20  ??

Comment: sorry for not closing, i was beaten to it

Comment: try this app: https://towardbrightspark.com. It is free and fun.