# Which books or content should I prefer to understand particle physics operator and representations

Tags: particle-physics, nuclear-physics, resource-recommendations, education, mathematics

I am just a intermediate passout and I want to know which books should I prefer for learning the mathematics of particle physics level like the different representation, operation like Hamiltonian,  Hamiltonian Mechanics, Lagrangian and every concept related to particle physics. 
I must tell you that I know little bit physics theorem and almost no mathematics background.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best books for mathematical background?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/193/)

Comment: I've suggested a duplicate because you serious lack of mathematics skills is a major handicap.  I would suggest, however, that you may find the mathematics not your forte - it's not for everyone - and hence your goal not realistic.

Comment: Actually I am good at mathematics of my intermediate level,  but lack any mathematical methods and knowledge of particle physics level. Brother, the book you mentioned can elevate my maths upto the level required by the field I want to explore,  what do you think?