# Solution set: Mathetmatical Methods For Physics

Tags: mathematical-physics, resource-recommendations, education, mathematics

Recently, I had a good start with H.W. Wyld on mathematical methods for Physics and now looking forward to ask whether is there any solutions available for the problems given at the end of each chapters?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Best books for mathematical background?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/193/)

Comment: I looking a kind of books like say for example for the heat analysis, how to do it, the problems it poses and different mathematical tools to solve it and so on...H.W. Wyld is not bad in that aspect and my focus will be solving them numerically

Answer (score 1):

If you have a background of Computational Electrodynamics, then your first destination to refer are as follows:

1. Numerical Techniques in Electromagnetics with MATLAB Hardcover by Matthew N.O. Sadiku
2. Computational Electromagnetics with MATLAB, Fourth Edition Hardcover by Matthew N.O. Sadiku

There are a few more specialised textbooks for Computational Electromagnetics which bring in Deep Learning and other major concepts, but these two would be a head start for you.

Comment: although he does algorithms in MATLAB, you can implement it easily in your language of choice.

Comment: although this doesn't answer your question in literal sense, I feel this is a worthy recommendation to you

Comment: I have implemented FMM (Single level) and MoM for Waveguides. What I try to understand or to have grip on is the problems and the methods to solve problems in Physics.

* MoM/FMM I followed the paper and just implemented but thinking was not deep enough.