# Best Calculus one book

Tags: resource-recommendations, differentiation, education, mathematics, calculus

I’m currently in my senior year of high-school. I’m planning to major in physics. I really enjoyed basic calculus but I really want to start studying it for real. I know university courses include calculus 1 2 3. I would like to start with calculus 1. I would like a suggestion for a book that would give me a thorough and deep understanding of calculus 1 and that would give me a head start in university, I want a hard book with many practice questions. Calculus is really interesting and I love it, I would really love to be fluent in it so I can easily understand the physics topics when I reach university. Any suggestion to what book is the best?

Comment: Would this question be better suited to [math.se]? Your goal may be physics, but the question is about calculus. Regardless, I always loved Thomas' Calculus, personally.

Comment: I found the book it’s almost 1200 pages, is all of it only calculus one!!???

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Best books for mathematical background?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/193/)

Comment: There is no calculus two book if you find a good calculus one book.

Comment: @HamzaEyad It covers calculus one through three. I think you will find that nearly all calculus books do so. In reality, there's not a hard distinction between the three courses, so it makes sense to package them together.

Comment: @HamzaEyad Looking back at the index, I would roughly say chapters 1,2 are "precalc", 3-6 are calc 1, 7 could be calc 1 or 2, 8-11 (possibly excluding 9) are calc 2, and 12-16 are calc 3. 17 would be like a little intro to differential equations.

Comment: Alright thanks a bunch. My journey shall soon start